# Imap connection refused

Tags: email, imap, postfix-mta, squirrelmail

I have been facing this issue the last few days and I would like some help please.
I have set my new Ubuntu server up and when I try to login to squirrelmail I get the following error.

`Error connecting to IMAP server: localhost.
111 : Connection refused`

Also when I try to telnet imap I receive the following error.

`telnet localhost 143`

`Trying ::1...`

`Trying 127.0.0.1...`

`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

I have also installed ISPConfig 3. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid dovecot settings. FIXED

Comment: So, which settings did you change?